# How to pass variables to function with selector swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to pass a variable to a function which is called within a selector but I'm getting the error 'Argument of #selector does not refer to an @objc method' how am I supposed to pass a variable to a function in a selector.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "compCell", for: indexPath) as! CompCell


    // creating the cell
    cell.postImage.downloadImage(from: self.winners[indexPath.row].pathToImage)
    print(self.winners[indexPath.row].votes)
    let num = self.winners[indexPath.row].votes!

    cell.votesLabel.text = "\(num) votes"
    cell.title.text = self.winners[indexPath.row].title
    cell.postID = self.winners[indexPath.row].postID
    cell.compID = self.winners[indexPath.row].compID
    //tempComp = cell


    let tap = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(caller(_pressed: cell)))
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(tap)


    return cell
}


func caller(_pressed: CompCell) {
      isPressed(_pressedCell: _pressed)
}

func isPressed(_pressedCell: CompCell) {
    self.selectedComp = _pressedCell
    //prepare(for: IndividualCompSegue, sender: <#T##Any?#>)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "IndividualCompSegue", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? IndividualCompViewController {
        destination.comp = self.selectedComp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass arbitrary values with the action of a `UIGestureRecognizer`.  An action takes one parameter which is the `UIGestureRecognizer` which triggers the action.

In your case, you can get the `cell` which triggered the tap with the `view` property of the gesture recognizer.

```
func tapHandler(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let cell = recognizer.view as? Compcell {
        isPressed(_pressedCell: cell)
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to detect taps, you need to create a `UITapGestureRecognizer`:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(tapHandler))
```

---

Instead of using a tap gesture recognizer to detect a selected cell, you can use

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = self.collectionView(collectionView, cellForItemAt: indexPath) as! CompCell
    isPressed(_pressedCell: cell)      
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I would do that? Sorry I'm new to Swift, thanks!

Comment: My cell is of type CompCell which is a UICollectionViewCell is that going to be an issue?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped `CompCell` as `UICompCell`.  I fixed the answer.

Comment: Why are you handling the tapping of a cell with a gesture recognizer and not just using the `collectionView(_:didSelectItem:at:)` method?

Comment: I wasn't aware of that method